# how to block access for non-authorized users to get pictures link from firestore storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have an image link that I want to protect for only authorize users but the issue whenever I try to get the link I can see the picture, even if I specify the rule for it ?

```js
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profiles/{userId}/{image} {
      // Read from storage !!
      allow get : if request.auth != null  // Authorized users only
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to [download URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), those are not at all controlled by security rules or any form of authentication.  Anyone who has the link can view the content.  That behavior can't be changed.

Comment: would they increase or count in bandwidth cost ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091607/cost-of-getting-url-of-a-firebase-image